# How to recover from the 'auth/credential-already-in-use' error when linking accounts

Tags: react-native-firebase

following this guide:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking
In my web app I was able to merge two accounts into one with no problem, 
but when I try to do the same in my mobile app:

```
//action to recover from the 'auth/credential-already-in-use'

// Get reference to the currently signed-in user
const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();
var prevUser = currentUser;
// Sign in user with another account
firebase.auth().signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(linkError.credential).then((userCredential) => {
  console.log("Sign In Success", userCredential.user);
  var newUser = userCredential.user;
  // Merge prevUser and newUser data stored in Firebase.
  // Note: How you handle this is specific to your application

    // After data is migrated delete the duplicate user
    return newUser.delete().then(() => {
      // Link the OAuth Credential to original account
      return prevUser.linkAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(linkError.credential);
    }).then(() => {
      // Sign in with the newly linked credential
      return firebase.auth().signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(linkError.credential).then(() => {
        return dispatch(mergeAccountsCompleted())
      })
    });
  })
```

The execution of prevUser.linkAndRetrieveDataWithCredential
fails with the error code: 'auth/no-current-user'
I couldn't find documentation for this error. So my question is, how can I recover from the auth/credential-already-in-use error when I want to merge the existing accounts in react-native-firebase ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about that - we had to drop support for credentials on error objects due to the difficulties I described in [this issue comment on GitHub](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/1329#issuecomment-410417367).

However, we have something planned that will be implemented at the earliest as part of the v5.0.0 release, or, at the latest in the v5.1.0 release.

Subscribe to the issue linked above and I'll update and close it when support has landed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but in my example I substitute the linkError.credential by a valid credential provided by the user, so my real problem is, if the prevUser hav'nt log out, after the newUser is deleted, in the execution of the return prevUser.linkAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(linkError.credential); line, why does it launch the 'auth/no-current-user' error ?